# why is the button not adding 5 to the element demo?

Tags: html, button

Why is the button not adding 5 to the x displayed in demo when clicked?

```
<h1>The += Operator</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var x = 10;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
function add(){
    x = x+=5;
}
</script>
<button onclick="add()"> += </button>

</body>
```

Comment: Because you’re not changing that element again. You’re only changing the variable. Also it’s `x += 5;`, not `x = x += 5;`.

Answer (score -1):

solved it, apparently code within a function cannot affect variables outside of it, this is my solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>The += Operator</h1>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        var x = 10;
        function add() {
            x = x+=5;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="add()"> += </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That’s not even true. That’s not even how you solved it.

Comment: sorry im really new to this. what makes the second one work then?

Comment: The first comment under the question should explain it.

Comment: While it technically works, `x = x+=5` is shorthand for `x = x = x + 5` which is unnecessary. You should either replace that line with `x = x + 5` or `x += 5` (the latter is shorthand for `x = x + 5`)

Another note, if you want the demo element to say "10" when you load the page, then you should have another `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;` outside the `add()` function.